# Laptop is overheating and lagging but doesn't shut down

Tags: sony-vaio, lag, overheating

I am using a Sony VAIO vgn-tz2500 laptop, and it's overheating when I watch Flash movies (Youtube etc.) and it starts to lag. I had a computer before that had problems with overheating but it shut itself down because of overheating, while this laptop doesn't! I dont know what is the problem here - is it about the cooling system or bad drivers, a virus? How do I fix this?

Comment: How did you determine that the laptop is actually overheating? Are you monitoring the temperatures? Can you hear the fan speed up and/or feel hot air blowing out of the vents? Have you checked to see if a process is hogging the CPU? Has the laptop always done this, or did it use to work fine before? Have you cleaned the fan and heatsink to remove accumulated dust? Can you provide more detailed specs (exact CPU and GPU models, RAM and HDD, operating system)?

Comment: Which Operating System is used on this PC? If it's W7, for example, you may check the power management to change the clock frequency to cool down that PC. On the other hand, if you're running Linux, you may have some problem of overheating... If it's Linux, which version? To make a long story short, help us to help you.  :)

Comment: @climenole yes I am using W7 and I dont know how to check the power managment :)

Comment: Check the "Power Options" in control panel. Just search this key word there... or run this command: RunDll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL powercfg.cpl :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notebook is equipped with Intel Core2 CPU that has a builtin thermal control. When the temperature of the CPU grows too high it just decreases the core frequency, thus reducing the power dissipated in a unit of time. Under normal circumstances of course it should not be overheating by running at full computational load, so you need to check the cooling system ([clean the fan](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01657439), e.t.c.)